# If $Im(z)>0$ and $Im(w)>0$, prove that $|z-\bar{w}|>|z-w|$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I'd like some feedback on my proof. Is it up to the standards of a graduate student? Are there any parts that remain unclear? Any suggestions on how to improve future proofs is also appreciated.

If $Im(z)>0$ and $Im(w)>0$, prove that $|z-\bar{w}|>|z-w|$

Let $z=x+iy$ and $w=a+ib\;$ both be complex numbers and $\;a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

$|z-\bar{w}|>|z-w| \iff |z-\bar{w}|^{2}>|z-w|^{2} \iff |z|^{2} -zw-\bar{z}\bar{w} +|w|^{2}>|z|^{2} -z\bar{w}-\bar{z}w +|w|^{2}$

$\iff -zw-\overline{zw}>z\bar{w}-\overline{z\bar{w}} \iff -2Re(zw)>-2Re(z\bar{w})$

Remember that $2\cdot Re(z) = z+\bar{z},\; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

As such, $-2Re(zw)>-2Re(z\bar{w}) \iff -ax+yb>-ax-yb \iff yb>-yb$

$ \iff Im(z)\cdot Im(w)>-Im(z)\cdot Im(w)$

which holds true since $Im(z)>0$ and $Im(w)>0$.

Comment: You can write `\operatorname{Re}(z)` and `\operatorname{Im}(z)` to make it look a bit nicer. There is also `\Re(z)` and `\Im(z)` which I personally do not like :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, comparing the squared distances is the right way to go.

You can shorten the argument to
$$
\begin{align}
 |z-\bar w|^2 - |z-w|^2 &= -zw - \bar z \bar w + z \bar w+\bar z w \\
 &= - (z- \bar z)(w-\bar w) \\
 &= - 2i \operatorname{Im}(z) \cdot 2i  \operatorname{Im}(w) \\
 &= 4 \operatorname{Im}(z) \cdot \operatorname{Im}(w) \\
 &> 0 \, .
\end{align}
$$

#### A geometric interpretation

The points $z, w, \bar w, \bar z$ form an [isosceles trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid) in the plane, with  $a=2\operatorname{Im}(z)$ and $b=2\operatorname{Im}(w)$ being the lengths of the parallel sides, $c=|z-w|$ the length of a leg, and $p=|z-\bar w|$ the length of the diagonal. So what we have derived is
$$
p = \sqrt{ab + c^2}
$$
and that is exactly the formula for the [length of the diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid#Diagonals_and_height). In particular, $p > c$.

Comment: I didn't think about its geometrical interpretation at all. Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 0):

Another geometric interpretation:  the real line is the perpendicuar bisector for the line-semgment from $w$ to $\overline{w}$.  Since $z$ is on the same side of the line as $w$, the distance $|z-w|$ is less than the distance $|z-\overline{w}|$.